# General function for reading numbers in Haskell

Tags: haskell, io, numbers

So, I wanted to get a `Float` from user and I have made this function :

```
getFloat :: IO Float
getFloat = do
    string <- getLine
    return (read string :: Float)
```

Now I would like to know how to make a more general function that can return ints, doubles and floats all in one go.

I have tried using `Num` type class to accomodate more possibilities but it doesn't work.

This is as far as I have got, it compiles but I'm not sure what I'm doing here exactly nor if it works at all.

```
etNumber :: (Read a) => IO a
getNumber = do
    string <- getLine
    return (read string)
```

Comment: `getNumber = readLn`.

Comment: yes, I know about readLn, but how can I re implement such function in this  style? @leftaroundabout

Comment: Well, you just did, your second version is exactly equivalent to `readLn`.

Comment: really? but I absolutely don't know how to get value from it. Say I want to read int from user, I have tried something like `num :: Int <- getNumber` but it doesn't work. @leftaroundabout

Comment: It should work alright. (Mind, that `x :: T <- action` syntax needs the `ScopedTypeVariables` extension, but with that (or the equivalent writing `num <- getNumber :: IO Int`) you should be fine).

Comment: snap! I have forgotten *IO* part.

Comment: Well, `num :: Int <- getNumber` is actually the best way to write this IMO. Only, as I said, you need to `:set -XScopedTypeVariables` to use that syntax (as  ghci suggests, BTW!)

Comment: Although I intuitivly get it, I'm still not sure why it needs to return something of a **Read** class, isn't the thing allready read in the `return` statement line? Shouldn't I be able to write definition like `getNumber :: IO Num`? It kind of makes more sense to me.

Comment: Why does it make more sense to you? How would you hope to use an action with such a signature? — Your action has “number” in its name, but it doesn't actually have anything to do with numbers, just with reading stuff from strings. **Therefore**, `Read` is the constraint you need. You can still add `Num` as an extra constraint, but this just makes it less general without changing anything at all. Better just drop `Number` from the name... i.e., simply use `readLn` right away (or some proper parsing library).

Comment: Because I'm returning number that I'll use in calculations and not something I will read later, that is allready taken care of in my function `read string`. At least that is my logic. Final result of my `getNumber` function should be `IO Num` type from which I can extract value that acts like a number and not member of `Read`. (I'm not exactly sure what I'm talking about here, still a bit confused :D)

Comment: It's analogue to my first `getFloat` function.

Comment: No, it's not analogue to `getFloat` because `Num` is a _type class_. Types (such a `Float`) and type classes are two completely and fundamentally different concepts. – I elaborate somewhat in my answer.

Comment: @Reygoch In this case, the class constraint is not about what you can do with the value later, but about how values of the given type can be built. Since you use `read`, you need to know that the type you're asking for can be constructed out of a `String` with `read` -- that is, that it is an instance of the `Read` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write the signature

```
getNumber' :: Num a => IO a
```

it means this action will need to be able to offer any result type `a` that the caller might request – provided the type is an instance of the `Num` class. So essentially, the action knows nothing about the type it has to produce, though it can use the methods of that particular `Num` instance:

```
class Num a where
  fromInteger :: Integer -> a
  (+) :: a -> a -> a
  ...
```

Note that this does not give you any tools to generate fractional/floating-pt. numbers, only integer ones. You could in fact write

```
getNumber' :: Num a => IO a
getNumber' = do
   i <- readLn
   return $ fromInteger i
```

but this is pretty useless, indeed it'll fail if you actually attempt to read something like `0.3` to a float – because that can't be pulled through the intermediate `Integer` type.

You could do this:

```
getNumber'' :: Fractional a => IO a
getNumber'' = do
   q <- readLn
   return $ fromRational q
```

in this case, the input will first be read as an arbitrary-precision rational type (which can deal with decimal-fraction input) and then converted to the desired final type, like `Double`<sup>1</sup>. However, this can *not* be an integer type, because those obviously could not handle the possible fractional inputs!

Maybe what you envision is this:

```
getNumber''' :: IO (∃a. Num a => a)
```

which would be an *existential type*. That's basically a constrained *dynamic type*, i.e. the type is not chosen at compile-type by inference from what the caller wants, but instead at runtime, choosing a suitable type that can properly deal with the particular string input (integer if possible, floating if needed).

Well, Haskell doesn't have<sup>2</sup> existential types, and [for good reasons](https://lukepalmer.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/haskell-antipattern-existential-typeclass/). Its standard parametric polymorphism is rather more useful because you actually get guarantees that some type will be exactly what you specify at compile time. Value should be integral? Make it an `Integer`; if then a decimal-fraction turns up in the input you get a meaningful error message right a way. Value might be fractional? Make it `Rational` or `Double`; these of course include integral values as well.

At any rate, there's no real reason to constrain the action to any numerical class. If you make it polymorphic at all, you should constrain it only as much as needed for the implementation (i.e., `Read`). To sum up: simply use `readLn`, don't write any `getTʏᴘᴇ` action at all.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>As a general rule, [never use `Float`](https://wiki.haskell.org/Performance/Floating_point) except when you're sure `Double` is not what you want.</sub>

<sup>2</sup><sub>Well, it has a (generally disrecommended) workaround: existentially qualified record constructors.</sub>

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
data SomeNum where
  SomeNum :: Num a => a -> SomeNum
getNumber'''' :: IO SomeNum
```

Comment: Thank you very much! You have really cleared it up for me. I think I understand now. I was expecting result type to be member of Num class since read can be used like this : `someNum = read string :: Int`